# What is this notation $\mathbb{Z}_3[x]_{x^2+1}$?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, notation, modular-arithmetic

What is this notation?

$$\mathbb{Z}_3[x]_{x^2+1}$$

I know $\mathbb{Z}_3[x]$ denotes the polynomials with coefficients in $\mathbb{Z}_3$. What does the $x^2+1$ bit denote?

Comment: [Localization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localization_(commutative_algebra))?

Comment: It's just the subring of rational functions of the form $p(x)/(x^2+1)^m$ for $m \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $p(x) \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$. There's nothing actually mysterious about this localization.

Comment: It is definitely a localization, and Joshua's interpretation is likely. As it happens, $x^2+1$ is an irreducible polynomial of $\Bbb{Z}_3[x]$, and therefore it generates a prime ideal 
$\mathfrak{p}=\langle x^2+1\rangle$. For some purposes a more useful localization would be $\Bbb{Z}_3[x]_{\mathfrak{p}}$, when the meaning is that this is the ring of rational functions of the form $p(x)/q(x)$ where $q(x)$ is NOT divisible by $x^2+1$. If that is the intended meaning, I think a symbol for the prime ideal is used as a subscript, but there may be some scope for ambiguuity. The context will tell.

Comment: Looks like my eye glided right over the 3 subscripts. I should have written $p(x) \in \mathbb{Z}_3[x]$. It seems quite unlikely to me that someone would use that notation to denote localization away from the prime ideal the element generates, though I suppose it's conceivable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is the notation used for the [localization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localization_(commutative_algebra)) of the ring $\mathbb Z_3[x]$ at the multiplicative subset $S=\{1,(x^2+1),(x^2+1)^2,(x^2+1)^3,\dots\}$.

That is, $\mathbb Z_3[x]_{x^2+1}=S^{-1}(\mathbb Z_3[x])$.